# How can I extend system default ButtonStyle class

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am looking to extend the system buttonstyle for example `BorderedButtonStyle` class and add my own custom configuration

I have tried

```
extension CrazyButtonStyle: BorderedButtonStyle{
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

but im getting an error `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'BorderedButtonStyle'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is possible only for classes, but majority of SwiftUI types are structs (ie. values), so we need to use composition instead, combining needed features with sequence of modifiers, like

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
// usage
Button("Demo") { }
    .buttonStyle(.crazy)


// calculable property extension
extension PrimitiveButtonStyle where Self == CrazyButtonStyle {
    static var crazy: CrazyButtonStyle { CrazyButtonStyle() }
}
```

[Complete code & demo is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Extend_builtIn_button_style.md)

#### Original variant:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
extension Button {
    func crazyButton() -> some View {
        self.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Crazy") {
        // ... action here
    }
    .crazyButton()
}
```

Comment: works but I would love to call it using the `.buttonStyle(.crazy)` or sth like that. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 2):

`works but I would love to call it using the .buttonStyle(.crazy) or sth like that. Would that be possible? –  Nic Wanavit`

**Asperi's answer is much cleaner, nonetheless**

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Button("Tap Me!")
        {
            print("button pressed!")
        }
        .buttonStyle(myButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct myButtonStyle: ButtonStyle
{
    // required method to conform to ButtonStyle protocol
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View
    {
        myButtonStyleView(configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    struct myButtonStyleView: View
    {
        let configuration: myButtonStyle.Configuration
        
        var body: some View
        {
            configuration
                .label // must be listed first
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```